# Как удалить данные из базы данных mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

Всем добрый день. Работаю с MySQL с Python. Подскажите, как можно удалить данные, которые засунул в бд, ровно через 5 часов? Есть ли такой метод, что вот как только засунул в бд, пошел обратный отчет и через 5 часов (не обязательно 5, может и 1 час) эти данные удалятся. Например, прога парсит название ролика и засовывает в бд, а через пол часа парсит другое название ролика другого видео и тоже засовывает в бд. И получается, на момент, как второе название добавится, то через 4 с половиной часа удалится первое название, а потом через 30 минут удалится второе название. Как такое осуществить? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Записывайте в БД время, когда эти данные были туда помещены. Потом в программе по таймеру отслеживаете старые записи и удаляете.

Comment: Элементарно. [EVENT Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).